# Clipper / DBF error

Tags: corruption, datafile

I'm not able to open a Clipper application (the app is 15 years old) because I'm getting :

`error dbfntx/1012 corruption detected`

Is there anyway to fix corrupted dbf files besides restoring from the last backup?

Comment: The corruption may be in the index(es), rather than the dbf. I would open the DBF using a plain DBF viewer first to check for DBF corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to Visual FoxPro command line window, type:

```
SET TABLEVALIDATE 11
USE "YourTable" EXCLUSIVE    && If the table is damaged VFP must display an error here
PACK    && To reindex the table and deleted "marked" records
PACK MEMO    && If you have memo fields
```

After doing that, the structure of the table must be valid.  If you want to see fields with invalid data, you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE EMPTY(YourField)   && All records with YourField empty
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE LEN(YourMemoField) > 200   && All records with a long memo field, there can be corrupted data
```

Or you may try to use following sources:

1. http://www.idganswers.com/question/14773/how-to-fix-dbf-file-error-missing-the-support-library
2. http://www.instructables.com/answers/Corrupt-dbf-file/

Answer (score 1):

The explanation of this error is [as follows](http://www.ousob.com/ng/53error/ng35950.php):

> DBFNTX/1012  Corruption detected
>
> Explanation:  File corruption has been detected in the specified
>     file.
>
> Action:  Make sure that the file type is correct for the operation.
>     For index files, make sure that the **type of index matches the driver
>     being used (e.g., .ntx for DBFNTX).**  Try recreating the database file
>     and/or index files.

It may mean that the database DBF file does not correspond with index files but also that you did not install proper drivers or something like that. I am no expert on clipper but check if your index files have .NTX extension or not. See also [this discussion](http://computer-programming-forum.com/19-clipper/e76e27b7b578a1ba.htm).

If it is ok, you may try some tools like [here](http://tags.topshareware.com/advanced-dbf-repair/downloads/1.htm).